# Show only a part of title (xcode)

Tags: uibutton

I have a string :"Send email to my friend". I want to have this string as a title of a button. But I just want to show only "Send email" and hide the rest of string. is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Add title to button as the text is never changing.

[myButton setTitle:@"Send email" ];

Or if you are getting this text at runtime, you need to do the string manipulation. Class reference for this is available at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on this?
Is it your application reads it from any variable/object reference?

You have to do string manipulation and then assign this to Button label.

Answer (score 0):

Just display the first x characters of the string.
[mystr substringToIndex:3];